# Is there a way to synchronize the scroll of two different scroll views which are on the same page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have two scroll views in my app. First one contains header of a list which works horizontally and the second contains the list which works horizontally and vertically ( in both directions). So now I want to synchronize the scroll of both scroll views. I want both scroll views work simultaneously.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, as I don't have any idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to look into the Scroll event and the Scroll To delegate action of a `ScrollView`

`Scrolled` event documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolled?view=xamarin-forms)

`ScrollToAsync` documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolltoasync?view=xamarin-forms)

Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve you could assign the the `ScrollView.Scrolled` event of each `ScrollView`:

```
ScrollView.Scrolled += ()=>{
     // If vertical get Scroll Y and translate it to your second ScrollViews Scroll X
     SecondScrollView.ScrollToAsync(ScrollView.ScrollX, SecondScrollView.ScrollY, true)
}

SecondScrollView.Scrolled += ()=>{
     // If vertical get Scroll X and translate it to your first ScrollViews Scroll Y
     ScrollView.ScrollToAsync(SecondScrollView.ScrollX, ScrollView.ScrollY, true)
}
```

I haven't had chance to test the above, it's more of a quick example to get you going in the right direction, a few things you'd have to look out for behavior wise is when `ScrollToAsync` is called it will likely fire off the scroll event of that `ScrollView` So you'll want to handle that to ensure there isn't some weird recursive behaviour.

Comment: @PrãshantSaraswat glad to hear it, if my answer above solved your problem feel free to mark it as the answer =)